# NCalc evaluation error no viable alternative at input ','

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, expression, ncalc

I'm trying to evaluate an expression using `NCalc`.

```
iif(fval(hopo_pfd)="true",fval(hopa_basic)*12%,0)
```

But this expression is producing an error

```
no viable alternative at input ',' at line 1:46
```

All functions declared here are custom functions. But the event `EvaluateFunction` is not even raised. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have invalid syntax. The expression: `fval(hopa_basic)*12%` includes the modulo `%` operator, but you haven't provided a divisor.

If you *meant* 12 *percent*, then it should be written in a decimal format: `fval(hopa_basic)*0.12`.

The reason it hasn't attempted to call `EvaluateFunction` to call your custom functions is because it failed to parse your expression *syntax*, let alone get to the stage of executing/resolving custom functions.