# NCalc using symbols in custom function name

Tags: c#, expression-evaluation, ncalc

Let's say that in my expression input I like to make functions stand out with a special prefix like `$`:

```
var expr = "Your name is $proper([firstName]) $upper([lastName])";
```

where I would write custom functions for `$proper` and `$upper`.

However, I get console errors "no viable alternative at character '$'".  It works if I get rid of the symbol, or use an underscore.

Is there a way to use symbol characters in function names in [NCalc](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/)?  This also doesn't work when the function begins with a number (as in, if I wanted to shorthand the function name `double` as `2x`).

(Sort of similar to [NCalc evaluation error no viable alternative at input ','](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534450/ncalc-evaluation-error-no-viable-alternative-at-input))

Comment: Somewhat like the syntax required by a similar parsing library ExpressionEval https://expressioneval.codeplex.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, this would require a change to NCalc's parser as a $ symbol cannot appear as part of a function name.  You could use something like `fnProper` and `fnUpper` instead if that would help.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh I was hoping there was just some undocumented or hidden feature that let you easily enable this, but I figured that was the case.

Comment: Personally, as a developer, I would find function names prefixed with a `$` symbol as confusing.  I would probably misread it as a variable name as is used in php.  Underscores are probably your closest bet as you've already worked out.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh yeah it depends on what language you're coming from -- to my developer eye I just wanted something to make a function stand out better as opposed to blending into a mathematical expression.  I was also looking for more cross-compatibility with the other parsing library ExpressionEval (which does use `$` prefixes) so I can transition existing expressions.